# What is the best implementation for recurring calculations with LocalDate on Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, java-8, localdate

I'm trying to find the best way to implement utils method for LocalDate on my app.

I need to add method logic for LocalDate. The functional use is to define if a localDate is a closing date or not, and calculate closing dates from LocalDate.

A Closing date is commonly the two first working days on a month.
So, from this functional requirement, I want to add this logic on my code with 3 methods :

```
boolean isClosingDate(LocalDate date){
...
}
```

Return true if the date is a closing date.

```
LocalDate getEndClosingDate(LocalDate date){
...
}
```

Return the last closing day from a day.

```
LocalDate getNextDayAfterClosing(LocalDate date){
...
}
```

Return the first non closing day of a month.

I don't need methods content because I exactly know how algorithme should be.

So, I need your help to find the best way on how to implement this logic on my spring app ? Do I must put there methods on a ClosingDateService ?

I thought to extends LocalDate with a "ClosingDate" class, but from the first boolean method "isClosingDate" it's conflicting because this implies that my object is not necessarily a ClosingDate.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: The answer depends on who is consuming the response.  If it's the UI, I'd put it in a controller.  If it's a controller or another service, put it in a service.  It could also be a model object method.  Why externalize that state if it's only required for an internal calculation?  Who knows?  "Best" is subjective.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The need is for a "back" calculation, so from your answer it should be on a service.
For you it should be a good practice to have a service named "ClosingDateService" who makes calculation from LocalDate and returns responses from the provided parameter ?

Comment: If it's a back calculation, I'd make that value available to the object doing the calculation.  If it can figure it out from the input data, it can do so without ever having to expose another public method.  It's called encapsulation and information hiding.  If no one else needs to know, don't expose it.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds pretty much like a business service to me.

Very roughly, there are basically two options:

- Put these methods in some (stateful) model class.
- Put them in some (stateless) service/component/utility class.

Let's see how it would work with a stateful model class. You can't extend `LocalDate` so you'd probably end up with something like `new ClosingDateCalculator(myLocalDate)` with methods `isClosingDate()`, `getEndClosingDate()`, `getNextDayAfterClosing()`. You won't need to pass `myLocalDate` as parameter to these methods anymore, otherwise passing it in constructor and consequently all the *statefullness* won't make any sense.

With the service you'll probably have `ClosingDateService` with methods `isClosingDate(date)`, `getEndClosingDate(date)`, `getNextDayAfterClosing(date)`, just as you specified in your question. Since `ClosingDateService` does not need to be initialized with any state, it can be managed (initialized, injected etc.) by Spring.

So it basically boils down to

```
new ClosingDateCalculator(myLocalDate).isClosingDate()
```

versus

```
 @Autowired
 private ClosingDateService closingDateService;
 // ...
 closingDateService.isClosingDate(myLocalDate);
```

I would definitely prefer the second option. I don't see much value in the first alternative so that it would cost me the whole DI machinery.

Answer (score 2):

I should make this a comment, but it will not fit, so plz treat it as a comment.

Oh my! we have close to the same thing in our application at the moment; no really, like the methods names are different, but the logic is 99% there. Initially this was a `static factory class` with static factory methods inside it as your might expect.

Later, I have re-factored and moved that to a `Service`; the reasons are pretty simple. First, it has grown too big and it was very hard to maintain. That is a minor argument - but the thing is that it contained utility methods from different logical places in a single place. Let me explain: I would like to be able to very easily add `HolidayClosingDatesService` or `AnniversaryContractService`, etc. These `names` make it very clear what these services are going to do, they also do a single thing logical to our app (as oppose to `DateUtils.isAnyversarryDateForUser` etc...). This is **especially** tricky once you will need to tie some User to a Date for example (and it seems like you will eventually). With Spring this is a breeze.

And the second one is `testing`. I can isolate the tests as much as I need to and test whatever I want. Having these as `spring services/beans` make this one really easy to do.